# Read in file and print only the last words of each line if these words are 8 characters or longer and dont contain #, @ or : symbols

Tags: python

so far i can write the code to filter out words that are less than 8 characters long and also the words that contain the #, @ or : symbols. However i cant figure out how to just get the last words. My code looks like this so far.

```
    f = open("file.txt").read()
    for words in f.split():
      if len(words) >= 8 and not "#" in words and not "@" in words and not ":" in words:
    print(words)
```

Edit - sorry im pretty new to this and so ive probably done something wrong above as well. The file is quite long so ill give the first line and the expected output. The first line is:

"I wish they would show out takes of Dick Cheney #GOPdebates Candidates went after @HillaryClinton 32 times in the #GOPdebate-but remained"

the expected output is "remained" however my code outputs "Candidates" and "remained".

Comment: can you show some line of your file ? and output expected

Comment: please give some sample input output

Comment: What do you mean by last words?? please add a sample file.txt file, and a sample output

Comment: Note that currently, your approach loses the concept of lines -- they are consumed by `.split()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in open(filename):
    if some_test(line):
       do_rad_thing(line)
```

I think is what you want .... you have the `some_test` part and the `do_rad_thing` part

Answer (score 0):

I think this works: you can open the file with readlines and pass the delimeter in split(), then get the last one using [-1].

f = open("file.txt").realines()
for line in f:
        last_word = line.split()[-1]

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what you are trying to do.
Split words of the file into an array using `.split()` and then access the last value using `[-1]`. I also put all the illegal characters into an array and just did a check to see if any of the chars in the `illegal_chars` array are in `last_word`.

```
f = open("file.txt").read()
illegal_chars = ["#", "@", ":"]
last_word = f.split()[-1]

if( len(last_word) >= 8 and illegal_chars not in last_word:
    print(last_word)
```